# Connect SAS on MAINFRAME to another DB using ODBC

Tags: dataset, odbc, sas, mainframe

My company has SAS 9.1 on a mainframe.  The mainframe also has SAS/CONNECT and SAS/SHARE.

Currently, we use 9.1 SAS for PC to connect to the Sybase database (via a ODBC connection) and we then upload the data we extract to the SAS mainframe.

Is it possible to connect the mainframe via ODBC to another database? 
We are trying to connect the mainframe to a Sybase Replication database. The Sybase database is currently sitting in a Unix server.

Does anyone know if what we're trying to do is possible? If so, any insight would be wonderful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can use ODBC on a mainframe or Unix server.

http://www.sas.com/offices/europe/uk/support/sas-hints-tips/ht1.html

You might want to contact your SAS representative to verify that this hasn't changed (or isn't wrong in general).  If it were possible to use ODBC on a mainframe, you'd need to license it, so your SAS sales representative should be able to tell you if that's possible or not.